# Android Support Design Library - Toolbar Error

Tags: android, xamarin, material-design

I've changed Navigation Drawer with Navigation view and it works well.

I was using following code to make all items white in action bar :

```
<.item name="android:textColorPrimary">
```

The problem is Navigationview gives error if I use this code.

How this could be possible while both library were written by Google ?

**PS : I work on Xamarin Android**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to have a `.` before `item`?, I believe it should read `<item name="android:textColorPrimary">` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Web site was hiding line so that is why I've added myself :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing things together now. Actionbar has nothing to do with the colors of the items in the NavigationView.
You should set the 'app:itemTextColor="#009688"' on the NavigationView to color the text of the items.

More on how to style the NavigationView you can find here: [How to customize item background and item text color inside NavigationView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594025/how-to-customize-item-background-and-item-text-color-inside-navigationview)

Comment: I am not trying to change anything on Navigationview. I am trying to change something on Support Toolbar and I've seen that someone suggested this solution.