# android navigation drawer icon tint of single item

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

i'm trying to change the tint of each icon in a navigation drawer individually with no success. 
I have tried :

```
<item
            android:id="@+id/nav_contacts"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_emergency"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:title="@string/emergency_contacts" />
```

which does not work, any  ideas ?

Comment: show your style.xml

Comment: worked around it , set the tint to null in code, and adjusting the fill of each icon

Answer (score 2):

you can set like this:

```
navigationView.getMenu()
    .findItem(R.id. navigation_item_1)
    .getIcon()
    .setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#b69260"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: Thanks. Icon has been changed but for title I have used Html text to get desired color. Is there different way to change text color too?

Comment: @nitinkumarp  see this:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594025/how-to-customize-item-background-and-item-text-color-inside-navigationview?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa