# Change background menuItem

Tags: android, menu

I have a menu in my android app, I am loading this menu in a `NavigationView`. I need change the background only in a item. I read the menu items and which I have to change the background from a `json` file form the server.

I tried this solution.

[How to customize item background and item text color inside NavigationView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594025/how-to-customize-item-background-and-item-text-color-inside-navigationview)

It works but I have a problem. When I select one option (without different background) it item get checked state and the background change to this item.

I tried to reset states when I close the menu (next code), but it doesn't work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mNavigationView.getMenu().size(); i++) {
        if (specialItem == mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(i)) {
            mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).setChecked(true);
        } else {
            mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).setChecked(false);
        }
    }
```

How I could reset the `menuItem` state to initial state when I close the menu?

Is it a good solution? could I solve it easily with other way?

Sorry for my English

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252939/change-background-color-of-single-specific-menu-items-of-navigationview

Comment: Hello Nilesh, than you for your answer.

Comment: did it help you?

Comment: I would like find a solution without use recyclerview, because the menu is working I just have to update it. With the recyclerview I have to update all menu logical, anyway I am going to try it.