# How to use Android Selector to change item color in PopupMenu?

Tags: java, android

I have a button in my OptionMenu which when touched will open a popup menu of items which are fetched at run time and added programmatically (so can't use hard coded xml menu items). I want to highlight a subset of these items according to their value, I used what is suggested here: [How to customize item background and item text color inside NavigationView?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366370/4960314) to try and get the items to be colored differently. However, all of the items are colored the same despite the `isChecked()` value being different.

Here is a small working example of the issue:
**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch(id) {
          case R.id.action_bar_button:{
            showMenu();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void showMenu() {
    View v = findViewById(R.id.action_bar_button);
    Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.MyPopupMenu);
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(wrapper, v);

    //Sample items to demonstrate the issue. I want the background to be red if false, blue if true
    Map<String, Boolean> list = new HashMap<>();
    list.put("Item 1", true);
    list.put("Item 2", false);
    list.put("Item 3", true);

    for(Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : list.entrySet()){
        String msg = entry.getKey();
        MenuItem item = popupMenu.getMenu().add(msg).setCheckable(true).setChecked(entry.getValue());
        System.out.println(item.getTitle() + ": " + item.isChecked());
    }
    popupMenu.show();
}
```

**styles.xml** contains:

```
<style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@drawable/menu_item_background</item>
</style>
```

**actionbar_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_button"
    android:title="List"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

**colors.xml** contains:
    `<color name="red">#ff0000</color>`
    `<color name="blue">#0000FF</color>`

And the **menu_item_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/red"  android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

However, when I run this I get the following:
[image: Actual Output]
As you can see although the `isChecked` state of Item 1 and 3 is true, they still appear red. The logcat output confirms this.

As an experiment I changed the `menu_item_background.xml` to use the `android:state_enabled` instead of checked and it works as expected:
[image]

What's going on here? Why doesn't this work with `android:state_checked`?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If your main motive is to highlight the selected item or similar kind of problem.
I would like to suggest as one of the solutions which worked for me to use spinner, which Popup Menu provides a similar dropdown option as Spinner, with a custom layout for dropdown, and change the background color at `getDropDownView()` at the adapter for the spinner.

**R.layout.spinner_item.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_context"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
/>
```

**R.layout.spinner_drop_down.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        >
<TextView
        style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_dropdown_text"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**UI Design**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
     <!--Some Layouts-->
     <Spinner
             android:id="@+id/spinner"
             android:layout_width="24dp"
             android:layout_height="24dp"
             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
             android:background="@drawable/icon"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:textDirection="firstStrongLtr"
             android:overlapAnchor="false"/>
     <!--Some More Layouts-->
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner)
val spinnerData = arrayListOf<String>("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3")
val arrayAdapter = object : ArrayAdapter<String>(activity!!.applicationContext,R.layout.spinner_item, spinnerData) {
                            override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
                                val spinnerItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_drop_down, null)

                                val dropDownText = spinnerItem.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.spinner_dropdown_text)
                                dropDownText.text = spinnerData[position]
                                val selected = spinner.selectedItemPosition
                                if (position == selected) spinnerItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)

                                return spinnerItem
                            }
                        }
arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_drop_down)
spinner.adapter = arrayAdapter
spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                                override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                                    //Do whatever you want to do when Item selected
                                }

                                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                                    //Do whatever you want to do when No Item selected
                                }
                            }
```