# NavigationView item selector does not highlight the enabled item

Tags: android, android-layout, navigationview

I'm trying to change the text color of the selected item in the NavigationView. Using the information for the [previous topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594025/how-to-customize-item-background-and-item-text-color-inside-navigationview) I set a selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/primaryColor" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/lightGrayColor" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

The `primaryColor` is blue. The NavigationView is as follows:

```
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/activity_nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nev_menu"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/menu_item_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/menu_item_selector" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

As you can see I set `app:itemTextColor` to `menu_item_selector`. But when I run the application, I see the selected item as grey. How does the `NavigationView` know which screen am I seeing right now? How do I fix it?

I'm using `onNavigationItemSelected` to switch between activities. Also I currently have only two windows - the dashboard and the logout. From the main screen I move to the dashboard (which contains the menu) and using the logout I go back to the main screen. Maybe the reason for it not working is because it does not know that the current screen is dashboard?

The `dashboard` java cotnains the following method:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        toolBar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolBar);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolBar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        View hView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    }

   @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.dashboard:
                // CURRENT ACTIVITY
                break;
            case R.id.messages:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MessagesActivity.class));
                break;
            case R.id.settings:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
                break;
            case R.id.about:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class));
                break;
            case R.id.logout:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                break;
        }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: In the `onNavigationItemSelected` method did you return `true`?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I did. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

For the initial look, you set a checked color to `primaryColor`, but overwrite it with `lightGrayColor` as you didn't specify the state that this color is available at; so you need to specify the state by `android:state_checked="false"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/primaryColor" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/lightGrayColor" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

You can also set the default selected item at the app start by trying any of:

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_item);
```

> **Update**

This is how it works with me

**Step 1:**  Use the same selector:

selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/primaryColor" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/lightGrayColor" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

**Step 2:**  use the xml attribute `app:itemTextColor` within `NavigationView` widget

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header_layout"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />
```

**Step 3:**
The previous step attribute won't work automatically as for some reason when you hit an item from the `NavigationView` menu, it doesn't consider this as a button check. So you need to manually get the selected item checked and clear the previously selected item. Use below listener to do that

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    // remove all colors of the items to the `unchecked` state of the selector
    removeColor(mNavigationView);

    // check the selected item to change its color set by the `checked` state of the selector
    item.setChecked(true);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.dashboard:
            // CURRENT ACTIVITY
            break;
        case R.id.messages:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MessagesActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.settings:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.about:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.logout:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            break;
    }

    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private void removeColor(NavigationView view) {
    for (int i = 0; i < view.getMenu().size(); i++) {
        MenuItem item = view.getMenu().getItem(i);
        item.setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

Now the text color will change perfectly.

**Step 4:**
To change icon colors, use the `app:iconTint` attribute in the `NavigationView` menu items, and set to the same selector.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_account"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
        android:title="My Account"
        app:iconTint="@drawable/selector" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:iconTint="@drawable/selector" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/logout"
        android:title="Log Out"
        app:iconTint="@drawable/selector" />
</menu>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The first solution didn't work for me. I also tried to change the colors in order to see if the selector is being used at all and it's being used. I prefer not to set it using Java, rather using the XML option.